# Ext Js store loaded on change tab

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, tabs, store

I’m trying to load a store on changing tabsPanels(Ext.tab.Panel) each tab is a different ViewModel, and every tab has a wrapper that contains a store that is global to everyone that will have a filter, like this:

Design of the way is display the pages:

[image]

1) is the view model were it has the reference to the wrapper,it’s a Ext.form.FieldSet

2) Is were the store is locate, also have reference there, it’s a Ext.panel.Panel

With this code I manage to get the store easily but only on the second time that I enter on the tab:

```
var vm = this.getView().lookupReference('commentwrapper').lookupReference('commentsList’).getViewModel();
console.log(vm);
console.log(vm.getStore('userTimeline'));
```

The problem comes when I change tabs I need to update and filter the new data. I ‘m using this code on the controller of each ViewModel:
PHP Code:

```
control: {
        '#': {
            activate: ‘functiontobe loaded’,
    }
}
```

My problem is the first time that I try to render I can’t get the data that is inside of the store only the second time.

Answer (score 0):

You could try use afterrender listener of tabpanel or tab item...

```
listeners: {
    afterrender: function(el) {
        // Now you can load any store you want
        el.getStore().load();
        // Or call some function after Tab will be activated
        el.on('activate', someFunction);
        // Or wait for store of any of your TabPanel Items will be loaded 
        el.getStore().on('load', function() {
           //some actions
        });
       // Also you can wait for any store load after your tab panel will be rendered
        Ext.getStore('App.store.Name').on('load', function(store) {
            // some actions on store load
        }); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Koshkin I will try it right away and let you know

Comment: I was able to call on active the Tab, now my problem is the first time when we call the store it is null only on the second one it appears all the data on it.

Comment: So you should use store.load() in activate listener and store.on('load'...) in afterrender listener of tab item.